# Trying to move/show/hide a Search Input on Mobile but Mobile version doesn't function because of non-unique ID

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

I have a search input box that displays on Desktop & Tablet. But for Mobile size it needs to appear on a completely different part of the page and in a different layout style. I tried display: none / display: block which displays & hides it fine. But the unique ID is the problem since the JS file reads it. The second **#text-search** ID (displaying on Mobile only) is being ignored and does not function because:
Found 2 elements with non-unique id #text-search

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have invalid HTML as you cannot have more than one element with the same ID on a page.

**Recommended:**
Do you have access to the search field's JS file? Would be best to have the code recognize search fields by class rather than by ID. Look to replace *getElementById()* for *getElementsByClassName()*?

**Alternative:**
This isn't a proper solution but the following code will remove the first time the element with the ID #text-search appears on the page...

```
$("#text-search").remove();
```

Good luck! And let me know how it goes. :-)

Comment: Brad thank you for your reply!  I found two instances in the JS. This is what I tried, but it seems to have broken the search:

**Changed:**  document.getElementById('text-search').value = contraFilters.search;
**To:**  document.getElementByClassName('text-search').value = contraFilters.search;

**Changed:**  d3.select('#text-search')
**To:**  d3.select('text-search')

Comment: Change “getElementByClassName” to “getElementsByClassName” (notice the plural in “Elements”). Also, change “select('text-search')” to “select('.text-search')”.

Comment: Good news. The first instance is working again now as a class. But the second instance (mobile) still isn't. This is my code:  
  
`<div class="hiddenFiltersMobile">  
        <input class="text-search" placeholder="Search..." style="width: 120px"/>  
</div>`  
  
`<div class="filters mobileFiltersPosition">  
<div style="float: left;">  
        <input class="text-search" placeholder="Search..." style="width: 115px"/> <i class="icon-download" style="font-size: 26px; color: #add8e6;"></i>  
</div>  
</div>`

Comment: I bet it because we are not running a JS loop for all instances of your search field. If you can send me your JS file or any JS related to your search field, we can solve this.

Comment: For sure. This is the main.js:  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10CEhq-N01Q3q7H7OkfIK08ATcliuIkMr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Oh man. This is a bit over my head. Though judging by your previous code. I am wondering if you could use CSS Media Queries to accomplish your goals.

Comment: That's basically what I did. I have the first Search input (desktop) which works, hide on mobile and then the second one appear on mobile. Except the second one doesn't actually function. Even now with a class assigned instead of an ID:  class="text-search"

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that perhaps you should delete your second search field and play with the CSS Media Queries of the first search field. So when it is mobile, the styling is different.

Might also be worth looking into another search JS that allows for multiple search fields on one page. A bit odd that their code does not allow multiple search fields.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Ya, just moving it instead of creating a second version is a possible option. Just a bit tricky and limited. One last question: That `$("#text-search").remove();` option that you mentioned. Where would I place that to disable the first #text-search ID if I try that route?